# Python: find the median carat of the premium diamonds

Tags: python, python-3.x

just started learning python and I am stuck on a question.

I need to find the median **carat** of the **premium** diamonds. So far I have the median, but I feel like I overcomplicated things. And I can't figure out how to get the median of only the "premium type diamonds.

```
        table2 = []

for i in range(1, len(table)):
    row = table[i]
    median_price = row[0]
    table2.append(median_price)

def my_median(sample):
    n = len(sample)
    index = n // 2
    if n % 2:
        return sorted(sample)[index]
    return sum(sorted(sample)[index - 1:index + 1]) / 2

print(my_median([median_price]))
```

[image: CSV File]

much appreciated

Comment: I don't know what a "premium" diamond is, but if you implement an "is_premium(diamond: Dict) -> bool" you can just do `statistics.median(d["carat"] for d in diamonds if is_premium(d))`

Comment: @Joe From the image, I need the median of all premium cut diamonds.

Comment: if premium refers to one of the values in the `cut` column, you should check that when processing the rows and ignore those entries with other values

Comment: You could loop over the ```cut``` column of your table, extract all the entries with ```premium``` label, and then check for the median like you did

Answer (score 0):

```
def median_premium_carat(table):
    premiums = [row
                for row in sorted(table)
                if row['cut'] == 'Premium'
               ] # sorting and filtering premiums
    median_row = premiums[len(premiums) // 2] # finding median row
    return median_row['carat']
```

Comment: To get list of premiums, "List comprehension" was used, hope you don't get confused.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.